# ZedGraph Only Graph non-holiday WeekDay Data?

Tags: c#, datetime, zedgraph

I'm working with stock charting, and it would be super helpful to be able to graph with a DateTime being the x-axis datatype, and double being the y-axis datatype.  Trouble is, with stock prices, there are no changes to the data on weekends or holidays, making graphs that include these meaningless days look funny.

How can I make it so I can create graphs that exclude holidays and weekends in the graph itself?

Comment: I'm curious as well, I looked at the source and didn't see anything to support this capability.

Comment: I'm having even more problems. If you want to use data more granular than daily, then you'll have to exclude time when the market is closed also (which can vary on half-day holidays).  What a  big headache! X(

Comment: Any luck with this?  Almost seems like you have to manage the x axis yourself.  I would think a class that maps datetimes onto the x axis and some methods on that class to allow the caller to exclude time ranges

Comment: This is a weekend project for me, I haven't given it much thought since I made the original post.  I will say this though, I did notice you can set the label of a point.  If you set the label of every point to a string representation of its date, and space everything out correctly (this is easier if all of your data is evenly spaced out, in the case of using only closing index values), I would imagine there's a way to label the x-axis using these point labels.  That's just a guess though...